# Calculating slope in negative, zero and positive domains

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Imagine a sine wave oscillating about a zero line. My task is to calculate the slope at several random points along the wave using a fairly coarse x-axis scale. (yes, this has a real application)

When the wave is in positive territory (above the zero line) slope can be calculated from:

```
Slope = (y(n) / y(n-1)) - 1
```

This yields +ve slope values heading up and -ve heading down.

The problem is that this must be switched when we are in -ve territory and then two more expressions are required when one of the values is zero for a total of four expressions that must be chosen programmatically with a conditional statement.

I would like to find ONE expression that covers all four conditions as this is at the center of a heavily travelled algorithm and click count!

I am sure this would be a trivial solution for a math genius, but to these tired eyes, it eludes me...

Added:

The "sine wave" is actually an MACD indicator that is derived from (random) price action of financial markets. An example would be here:

http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:moving_average_conve

The slope (of the thick black line in the lower graph for example) is what I need to calculate here, defined simply as up or down (where heading up is positive)

The problem is that both +ve and -ve slope can occur above and below zero. A slope calculation may also occur using increments that cross the zero line and at the zero line.

It would be nice to find a solution that not involve a ton of IF statements... like, for example, shifting all the y values by a fixed amount, so they become positive and then calculating slope in the +ve region. I would need to pick a number that historically, y has never been below, like a couple of orders of magnitude for example (99) and then I could perform the offset and one slope calculation?

Comment: That function doesn't compute the slope, which is why you're having the problem you are... Do you specifically need the slope, or is the upness or downness enough? Or do you actually want the ratio, which is what you're getting from your equation?

Comment: What Stobor just asked. I also would like to know if this sine wave has a known equation, in which case this is not even an issue since you can calculate the derivative analytically at any given moment. But perhaps you have some measured data from e.g. an oscilloscope or similar? Please provide with more information.

Comment: >That function doesn't compute the slope. what does it compute then?
No there is no know function for the graph. it can be considered random.

Comment: So did you arrive at an answer here? I read through the responses and I'm not clear there was an answer. Would be nice to see a conclusion that had clarity for others who read the posting. Thanks for the interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

what do you mean by 'sine wave'? do you mean a mathematically generated plot of `y = a sin(bx)` or a smooth curve fitted to some experimental points via splines that just happens to resemble a sine wave in that it oscillates around the x axis? if the former, you can differentiate it mathematically and get the exact slope at any point. if the latter, the formula you're looking for is

```
slope(x) = (y(x-delta) - y(x+delta))/(2 * delta)
```

experiment with different values of delta. there're no conditionals involved; the signs of the numerator and denominator will automatically ensure that you get the right sign for the slope.

Comment: Shouldn't you be dividing by 2 delta?

Comment: Thank you for a very informative answer. I should have explained the underlying data series is essentially random (see added above)
What would the differential look like as a function?

Comment: mike: the concept of a slope at a point requires that your curve is continuous. if your plot is a series of discrete, random points you need to first fit a smooth curve through it (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting for some ways to do this) and then calculate the slope of the curve based on the equation you used to generate it. if you are more interested in the trend of the curve, you can use the formula i supplied above. what it does is take a window (delta) around the point you want, draw two vertical lines, see where they cross the curve and join those points with a line.

Comment: Hi Matin, Thankyou for the reply. Yes the curve must be smooth. This is a function of the timeframe and the lookbackk used for the indicator. It is essentially smoothed as it is based on a moving average of longer period. Th vertical lines are in fact the increment of the timeframe (y-axis)

Comment: mike: one thing i think you need to be careful about is to calculate the slope at a point x by taking a window *around* x, rather than a window whose right hand side is x. also, if your curve is plotted via discrete ticks, even a moving average isn't really "smooth" in the mathematical sense, but that doesn't really matter for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The slope is just

```
slope = y(n)-y(n-1)
```

Or if you have units on the x-axis, divide this by one x-axis step (i.e. x(n)-x(n-1)).

This formula is sort-of the definition, and it doesn't matter which side of the x-axis your are on.  (I say "sort-of" here, since the slope is a limit of this equation as you sample bins get very close together, so this equation is an approximation, and other approximations can be used.)

Keep in mind that the slope of noisy data will look even more noisy.

I suspect the first few paragraphs of the [slope page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) will help you out with this.

Comment: yes, but when the values are -ve the slope becomes y(n-1) - y(n). When one value is +ve or zero it is different again...

Comment: No, the formula really doesn't change.  For example, shift the curve up or down, positive or negative doesn't change the slope, in reality, or in this formula.  (Here's a little proof: To shift up or down, add a constant, say C, to every point, so Y(n) = y(n) + C.  Then Y(n)-Y(n-1) = (y(n)+C) - (y(n-1)+C) = y(n)-y(n-1) + C - C = y(n) - y(n-1).  That is the **same** slope.)  Maybe try putting the real data aside, and try this type of thing with a real sine curve, for example.

Comment: Maybe an example would clarify? Say y(n)=30 and y(n-1)=10; then the slope is 30-10=20. Shift down by 20, y(n)=10, and y(n-1)=-10; then slope = 10-(-10) = 10+10 = 20. Shift the original down by 40, y(n)=-10 and y(n-1)=-30; then slope=-10-(-30)=-10+30=20. The same every time with exactly the same formula.

Comment: Tom, you are not understanding. When the the curve is in the -ve domain a rising slope has lesser negative y values. In the +ve domain it has increasing values of the y-axis. Meaning, going up in the negative domain means decreasing -ve values whereas goin up in the posative domain means INCREASING +ve values. Then if you add in the cases where one value is the opposite sign or zero, you have 6 or so cases to define. Shifting the values into the +ve doamin solves this issue.

Comment: Mike, I might be misunderstanding. Can you give me, or post in your question statement, an example using actual numbers, sort of like I did in the comment above, where the direct subtraction in the above equation doesn't give the correct slope.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the slope of the sine wave, it's done via standard calculus functions.

The slope of the line `f(x)=sin(x)` is `f'(x)=cos(x)`.

However, based on your formula, I'm not entirely sure that's what you're after. Maybe you need to clarify it.

But if you want the approach as shown in your question, I think your concern about performance is misplaced here. In order to do this calculation as a single arithmetic expression, you're going to have to multiply by -1 depending on whether you're above or below the x-axis (and whether you're transitioning across that axis from f(n-1) to f(n)).

That's likely to be slower (or at least no faster) than a simple sequence of if-statements once it's been compiled down to machine language.

As with all optimizations, you should choose the easiest-to-develop approach first *then* see if it has performance problems. Otherwise you may be wasting a lot of effort up front for an unneeded boost.

Comment: Very good advice. I was hoping there was an elegant solution like shifing all the values by a fixed offset so they become +v and then calculating slope

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the slope; you can do something like this:

```
(iMACD(NULL,0,12,26,9,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_SIGNAL,0) ) < 
iMACD(NULL,0,12,26,9,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_SIGNAL,2)
```

means decreasing. Else increasing graph, provided that:

```
(iMACD(NULL,0,12,26,9,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_SIGNAL,0) ) >0
```